# Confusion over the Android Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, sleep, activity-lifecycle

I have an app which is one activity.

Everything works as I would expect except when I put the phone (a Samsung Galaxy Ace running Gingerbread) to sleep with the button on the side.  When I do this, the following are called (in this order):

**onPause, onStop, onDestroy, onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause**.

This is *without waking the phone up*, it is still asleep - screen is off.

Why is the activity killed completely and re-recreated?

Even more bizarre, if the phone is then switched back on the following happens:

**onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroyed, onCreate, onStart, onResume**

Even though it's 'ready to go' (sitting in onPause), it gets killed and re-created all over again.

If the app is running and I press Home then the activity is only stopped, not killed, once stopped, I can then put the phone to sleep and then wake it up again and the activity is never killed.  It just goes to onRestart etc... which is what I would expect.

This behaviour only occurs when the phone is put to sleep while the activity is running (and in the foreground).

I've read the docs on the Activity Lifecycle but I can't figure out why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: Have you seen this multiple times? I'm wondering if you accidentally tilted the phone to cause an orientation change as you turned it off, which was then processed before the phone went to sleep.  That would cause exactly what you saw.

Comment: Hi @flightplanner, thanks for the comment, I've tried it multiple times - it happens every time.  Also I've also tried holding the phone steady in horizontal and then vertical orienations when doing this being very careful not to tilt the phone.

Comment: Is your `Activity` orientation set to `landscape` only?

Comment: Sounds like it is triggering a configuration change (of some kind) when going to sleep or waking up. Could be a bug on this particular device (or this particular version of Android from Samsung).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same behaviour on other Samsung device when the `Activity` is forced to be shown in landscape (set in AndroidManifest.xml).

This happens because the device lock screen is forced to be shown in portrait and while it is in front of your application, it forces your top level `Activity` into portrait.

This is nothing to worry about and also nothing you can change.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks @MaciejGórski, I am indeed forcing my activity into landscape mode in the Manifest, it is annoying though as the app re-starts from scratch (right from the loading screen) whereas on other devices it just picks up where it left off.  Thanks though at least I know what is causing it, it was driving me crazy! :-)